# Web is PHP 7.0 but in CLI it's using 5.6

Tags: apache, php-7, php-5.6

Been trying to fix this for hours now. So here goes. I upgraded my PHP a month ago from PHP56 to PHP70. On my terminal I sed php -v and on the web a phpinfo() and it truly showed a PHP70 version. Now here is my problem, I have a cron job and a particular packaged that I used is required to use PHP7. When I tried to phpinfo() using CLI it showed that it is using PHP56

BTW - I'm using MacOS Sierra.

My httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
#LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/php5-7.0.15-20170213-103227/libphp7.so
```

Tried commenting either of the two php5_module and php7_module but nothing works :(.

Regards,

Comment: My spidy senses say it has something to do with cli export, ~> `export PHPVERSION=7.0-cli; php -v`

Comment: it still doesnt work. I even tried adding this to my .zshrc and .bash_profile: export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH. And my php5 is a symlink to php5-7.0.15-20170213-103227

Answer (score 0):

If you installed `php56` with `brew`, you should try to do the following:

- `brew update && brew upgrade`
- `brew tap homebrew/dupes`
- `brew tap homebrew/versions`
- `brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php`
- `brew unlink php56`
- `brew install php70`

You might get an error if PHP 5.6 has not been installed by brew previously, but don't worry, you can simply continue

- `export PATH=/usr/local/php70/bin:$PATH`